# How do I pass a parameter from a querystring to a component registration in Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

Im building a web application and I'm using AutoFac for dependency injection.

For this project, when I resolve the dependencies for DbContext of Entity Framework, I need to pass a custom parameter, because the connection string is dynamic and can change depending of this parameter.

This parameter comes from query string (from another application). I need to somehow intercept it, take this value before the initialization of the Injector, but I don't know the best approach for doing this, since the initialization of the Injector is in the Application_Start() method.

So, I have the following code:

```
//Entity Framework DbContext
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(int portalCode){...}
}

//AutoFac registering:
container.Register<MyContext>(c => new MyContext(how to pass the parameter here ??)).InstancePerRequest();
```

Where container is the default `ContainerBuilder`

And then, calling the AutofacInitialize in`Application_Start()` just like it is in the AutoFac Doc.

How do I achieve that during the Dependency Resolver with Autofac?

Comment: In your particular case, the query string is *runtime data*. You should not construct application components using runtime data. Please take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) that explains why not and how to design your application instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you may simply do like this:

```
builder.Register<MyContext>(c => 
    new MyContext(int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["PortalCode"])))
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Or a more verbose solution using a provider class

```
public interface IPortalCodeProvider
{
    int GetPortalCode();
}

public class PortalCodeProvider : IPortalCodeProvider
{
    public const string PortalCodeQueryStringKey = "PortalCode";
    public const int DefaultPortalCode = 123;

    public int GetPortalCode()
    {
        var portalCodeString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[PortalCodeQueryStringKey];
        int portalCode;
        if (int.TryParse(portalCodeString, out portalCode)) return portalCode;
        else return DefaultPortalCode;
    }
}
```

MyContext `ctor` signature would be `MyContext(IPortalCodeProvider portalCodeProvider)`

Autofac class registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<PortalCodeProvider>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Good solution, that's what I was looking for.
Quite simple and understandable.

Comment: @MichaelMao, you have to put it in your **composition root**. For MVC application it is **Application_Start()**, provided you have a reference to **Autofac** and **Autofac.Integration.Mvc** in your project.
Initialize builder, `var builder = new ContainerBuilder();`, register dependecies, get **container** `var container = builder.Build();` and later `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));`

Comment: I think Application_Start method will only run one time when application start so how it could get the HttpContext query string? That's the point I can't unserstand

Comment: The Request object is not available during Application_Start.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a variable for the parameter value:

```
var parameter = "my value";
container.Register<MyContext>(c => new MyContext(parameter)).InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: I've edited my question, the parameter comes from a query string. I need to intercept during the call of the Injector, in Application_Start() method.